# How to unlock using lockf()?

Tags: c, linux, file, unix, flock

I want to read from txt file and append the next number in it, I want to use fork as well to work as a second process. In following code, I need help to unlock the file. I am unable to unlock the file.

```
int main() {
  int x;
  pid_t child = fork();
  FILE *file;
  //flock(fileno(file),LOCK_EX);
  file = fopen ("list.txt", "r");
  //printf("file is locked");
  int fdSource = (int)file;
  if (fdSource > 0){
    if (lockf(fdSource, F_LOCK, 0) == -1)
       x = readValue(file);
       return 0; /* FAILURE */
    }
    else {
      return 1;
    }
    if (lockf(fdSource, F_ULOCK, 0) == -1){
       printf("file is not lock");
       appendValue(x);
    }
    else {
       return 1;
    }
    appendValue(x);
}
```

Comment: `int fdSource = (int)file;` is not right. Look at the man page for `fileno(3)`.

Comment: Thank you, but if do not use (int) before that I got error and advise to cast it

Comment: Casting to remove a warning is a big mistake in 99.999999% of the cases in C. Use the function I mentioned above to get a file descriptor from a `FILE*`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please put more effort into editing your question, there are already typos in the title. Also it is important that you tag your question correctly, just C is not sufficient here. `lockf` is part of your OS and not of your programming language.

Comment: Your code is using `lockf()`; your title originally said `flock()`.  You can use either of those, or `fcntl()` — such an embarrassment of riches — to do the locking, but you should be self-consistent.

Comment: Also note that locks are (usually) advisory, not mandatory.  That is, your child process will not be impeded by the parent holding a lock on the file unless it looks to check whether the file is locked.  Note, too, that system calls use file descriptors, not file streams (file pointers).  If you must open a file stream, then use `fileno(fp)` to obtain the file descriptor for the file stream.  The name `fd` is often used for a file descriptor, and the name `fp` is often used for a file stream.

Answer (score 4):

Replace `int fdSource = (int)file;` with this:

```
int fd = fileno(file);
```

Also, if you are on a UNIX, you want `flock`, not `lockf`. To lock, do this:

```
flock(fd, LOCK_EX);
```

And to unlock:

```
flock(fd, LOCK_UN);
```

Comment: `lockf()` is also a valid locking function on Unix, as is `fcntl()`.  I agree the title asked about `flock()` but the code used `lockf()`, so I've made the title of the question match the code (simpler than making the code match the title).

Comment: I need to read from one process and append by other process. But here in my code fork is creating two process, which reading two time and appending to file two time e.g, it add 1 2 3 to file and then second process add 4 5 6 to txt file.

Comment: using if(child == 0){  codes..} I am able to append only once time